# ListView CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE change color of the radio button

Tags: android, xml, listview, radio-button

i create costume alert with listView type CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE ,my issue its how to change the color of the radio button,i read some question and understood that i need to change the style but still it dose not working.
photo of my pop alert:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLHF.jpg

here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.example.hercules.animal_app.Activity.ResultFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/realtiveLaoutListView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="360dp">
    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/titeleListView"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Choose animal"
        android:textColor="#ff7042"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        style="@style/myStyle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAppBackGroundButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/titeleListView"
        android:id="@+id/typeListView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/typeListView"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seperator"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cancelButtonChooseArray"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff7042"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/okButtonChooseArray"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff7042"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_below="@id/seperator"/>
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any idea for this question ?

Comment: i already found soltuion,at the manifest you can change the color of the primary and it will be works,or create your own style      `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>`